# When is the http-on-examine-response topic issued?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to check for a 302 response in a Firefox addon using this rather common piece of observer code but the `http-on-examine-response` is almost never issued even on a page with a 302 redirect.

```
var httpRequestObserver = {
  observe: function (subject, topic, data) {
    console.log(topic)
    if (topic == 'http-on-examine-response') {
      subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
      try {
        this.handleRequest(subject);
      } catch(error) {
        console.error(error.message)
      }
    }
  },
  handleRequest: function(oHTTP) {
    var uri = oHTTP.URI.asciiSpec;
    console.log(oHTTP.responseStatus, uri);
  }
};
Services.obs.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, 'http-on-modify-request', false);
```

The only topic being issued/printed is `http-on-modify-request` which is useless when you want the response status. I get errors like this:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIHttpChannel.responseStatus]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, bad copy pasta. The second argument to the `addObserver` method should be the topic you want to be notified on

```
Services.obs.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, 'http-on-examine-response', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to read the response status when it's not yet available in the HTTPChannel, though that's pretty weird.
It works flawlessly in my requestmod module (available on NPM), which implements an SDK-like wrapper around the HTTP channel observers and I cannot spot where your code would handle things differently.

Alternatively I would suggest using WebRequest.jsm, which is designed for usage by extensions. Specifically its onHeadersReceived listener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/WebRequest.jsm#onHeadersReceived

Your code would look like this:

```
let { WebRequest } = require("resource://gre/modules/WebRequest.jsm");

WebRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function handleRequest(response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode, response.url);
});
```

The only "drawback" of WebRequest.jsm is, that it doesn't work with the current stable version of Firefox, but that'll change soon...

Also note, that you should remove the listener again when your extension is unloaded - but the same rule applies for observers.